# how to make background image full-appear

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when I want a header and under it there is an image. When The image width is larger than the header one, a scrollbar appears. When you scroll to right there is blank space in header.
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Bz8/6/) the example problem.

the problem is that every page has image with different width. When I use the largest image width on header, a horizontal scroll appears.

Comment: You can assign width of 100% to the image and it will auto resize itself. [jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Bz8/7/) - original image is 1600x1200.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, il would put the header a fixed size or a 100% width size and do the same on the image.

You can also use the property max-width on the image so that she can't be sized more than 100% : add the following rule (in css) in your fiddle example :

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: There's a w3 draft of the css `object-fit` property that allows for the same values  as `background-size` such as  `cover` and  `contain`, but for image elements, not background images. This should probably be used here in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact set up - but if you have the ability to tweak the CSS so that you can create a rule for each page - I'd add the images as backgrounds to your header.

```
 .header {
     background: url(example.jpg) no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
   }

 .page-1 .header {
     background-image: url(example-1.jpg);
  }

  .page-2 .header {
     background-image: url(example-2.jpg);
   }
```

[See this page on the background-size property](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/).